# How add class, while start entering text into text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello friends I am trying to add class while entering text into text field , can tell me the right way

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

And after Enter text into text field

```
<input type="text" name="fname" class="test">
```

This should add class

Comment: "While entering" meaning once a character has been typed?

Comment: yes, When i start entering text, this should add class and after removing text this should remover class

Answer (score 1):

To add class to textbox as user enter some text in it

use keypress event to add class while user start entering text:

```
$("input[name='fname']").keypress(function(){
 $(this).addClass('test');
});
```

use blur event to remove class as use complete entering text:

```
$("input[name='fname']").blur(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('test');
});
```

Comment: How does blur relate to a user entering text?

Comment: OP has told "And after Enter text into text field This should add class "..that why blur has been used...

Comment: Still, blur comes after the input loses focus, not after text has been entered. Keyup is probably a better choice.

Comment: as use complete text entering obviously focus will be lose

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch event while entering text, you can use `keyup()` function :

```
$("input[name='fname']").keyup(function(){
 $(this).addClass('test');
});
```

**Source:** https://api.jquery.com/keyup/